# Why {x <= 10 ^ x < 10} is simplified to {x < 10} instead of {x <= 10} in Hoare's logic?

Tags: algorithm

Currently I'm studying Hoare logic to learn about program correctness. Particularly, I'm reading [Hoare logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic#While_rule) and I'm analyzing the following example from the while rule: 
[image: while rule example]

What I want to know is about the simplification step: why `{x <= 10 ^ x < 10}` is simplified to `{x < 10}` instead of `{x <= 10}`?

Comment: Consider the case `x = 10`. This does not meet the original condition or the simplified version, but it does meet yours. `x <= 10 /\ x < 10` is equivalent to `(x < 10 \/ x = 10) /\ x < 10` (by def of `<=`) is equivalent to `(x < 10 /\ x < 10) \/ (x = 10 /\ x < 10)` (distribution) is equivalent to `x < 10 \/ (x = 10 /\ x < 10)` (deduplication) is equivalent to  `x < 10 \/ _|_` (can't be both less than and equal to something) is equivalent to `x < 10` (identity of disjunction).

Answer (score 3):

The statement is saying: "Condition1 AND Condition2", where Condition2 (`<`) is more restrictive than Condition1 (`<=`).

Certainly, anything that satisfies both (due to the "AND") must also satisfy the more restrictive one.

So, it suffices to just use the more restrictive condition by itself. The other condition is superfluous.

---

Put another way: the only difference between `<=` and `<` is the `==` case. Nothing that satisfies the `==` case could possibly satisfy the more restrictive `<` case, so there's no point checking for it.

Also, you might want to check https://math.stackexchange.com/ for pure math/logic questions.

Comment: therefore the proposition is being strengthened?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @jwd. I've put the question here because I think it is also related with Algorithm Analysis and Design. (It's a course I'm following this semester in my University.)

Comment: @JohnOrtizOrdoñez I don't know about it being strengthened, but maybe "not weakened" would be accurate (:  If you can express the same thing in a simpler way without weakening the meaning, you might as well just use the simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you were to choose a new tablet, and you wanted it to have (1) a big screen AND (2) a screen that is bigger than 20cm. You can clearly discard the first condition because the first one will only be true when the second one is also true.

In your case, the "a big screen" condition is your `x <= 10`, and the "a screen that is bigger than 20cm" is your `x < 10`. **All cases** that satisfy both of them also satisfy `x < 10`. The more "relaxed" condition `x <= 10` can then be thrown away.

Comment: This waffle relies on the hidden assumption that 'big' means '>= 20cm'.

Comment: No no... if you said that, then (1) and (2) would be the same condition. `big` could mean any size smaller than `20cm`, but when I wrote this answer, I was (truly) based on the idea that [`big` would mean something like `>= 17cm`](http://i.imgur.com/p0Fu6Nv.jpg). [but I didn't want to mention it because it was totally offtopic =)]